# Connecting an Operator with a Panel Float Slider

Tags: interface, add-on, properties, operator, panel

I have a very basic question about Operators and Properties. I can't wrap my mind around how I'd make a Float slider in a Panel that affects a selected object in the 3D view as I drag it in real time.  I understand how to add the Float to my panel, but how do I connect this with an Operator? I don't want to have to push the Operator button to get this to work.

```py
import bpy
 
class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    translate_x : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="",soft_min=0, soft_max=1000)

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        layout.prop(mytool, "translate_x")
        layout.operator("addonname.myop_operator")

class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Translate X"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        bpy.context.object.location[0] = mytool.translate_x
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Could anyone please help?

[image: Panel]

Comment: I found a solution in this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78870/making-property-sliders-act-similar-to-operators